# How can I setup classes with images that have nothing in common with each other using SVM?

Tags: svm

I have images that are easy to classify like: square, arrows, triangle etc
I have also images that i call "others" that cannot easily be classified into squares, arrows, or triangles and that they have nothing in common with each other!
Should these other images be compiled into one large class "other" or discarded from the training set?

Comment: are the other images noise?  When you say that they have nothing in common with each other you mean that they are each truly unique?  Why are they part of the data-set?

Comment: @Alos: probably trafic signs within a road-image. The others would be "the world"